# Tornado authentication help

Tags: python, tornado

I just started using tornado and got it set up with nginx proxing tornado and php and everything is working corretly

What im trying to achieve is a notification system.

When a user does something such as send an email or update a field in the database if the other user is browsing the web he will get notified.

So using jquery ajax I will send the message and the name of the user to tornado. 
I got that part working. ex:

```
 $.ajax({url: "/send/notification", data: "data//Serialise from form , dataType: "text", type: "POST",

            success: function(response) {

                alert("Message From Tornado : "+response);

    }, error: function(response) {

        console.log("ERROR:", response)

        alert("Failed");

    }});
```

Then on Tornado get the name of the recipient

```
recipient = self.get_argument("recipient", None)
```

Now Using jquery ajax function to long poll tornado for a response.
But im completly lost on how to make tornado check if that notification is for him and if so send him data.

something like

```
if self.current_user == recipient:
   self.write(some data);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite that simple. You need to keep a list of waiting messages, and the users they are for. The example [chat application](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/chat/chatdemo.py) is probably the best place to start, although it just delivers each message to everyone.

However, it shouldn't be too hard to modify. You could, for example, add a `dict` mapping users to waiting messages, and when the poll for new messages occurs, check if there are any messages for that user. Or you could just do a quick and dirty iteratation through all messages on every poll.